# Toast UI Calendar event detail popup out of view

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to display details of an event using the toast ui calendar's default popup function in a chrome extension. The problem is that the popup seems to be rendered outside of the view port. I am using Node js

html:

```
                   <div class="container-wrapper">

                        <div class="container-widget">

                            <div class="innerWidget">

                                <h1>Today</h1>

                                <div id="calendar" style="height: 300px"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="innerWidget">
                                <h1>Overview (coming soon)</h1>
                                <canvas id="weeklyChart"></canvas>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

JS:

```
import Calendar from '@toast-ui/calendar';
import '@toast-ui/calendar/dist/toastui-calendar.min.css';
import 'tui-date-picker/dist/tui-date-picker.css';
import 'tui-time-picker/dist/tui-time-picker.css';
import 'tui-date-picker/dist/tui-date-picker.js';
import 'tui-time-picker/dist/tui-time-picker.js';

const calendar = new Calendar('#calendar', {
    usageStatistics: false,
    week: {
        taskView: false,
        eventView: ['time'],
    },
    defaultView: 'day',
    useDetailPopup: true,
});
```

CSS:

```
.container-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.container-widget {
    width: 250px;
    height: 300px;
    padding: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
    border-radius: 20px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;

}

.container-widget:first-child {
    margin-right: 15px;
}

.container-widget:only-child {
    margin-right: 0px;
}

/* Media query for screens with a width of 600px or more */
@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
    .container-wrapper {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
    }

    .container-widget:only-child {
        width: 800px;
        height: fit-content;
    }
}

/* Media query for screens with a width less than 600px */
@media screen and (max-width: 599px) {
    .container-wrapper {
        display: block;
    }

    .container-widget:only-child {
        width: 250px;
        height: fit-content;
    }
}
.innerWidget {
    margin: 20px;
    display: block;
}
```

I would appreciate your advice!

I have tried changing the css of the node package (no idea if that works), by adding a z-index value that is higher than my other values.